# Protocol Buffer Challenge

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am developing an application that uses the protocol buffer as a serializer . My application will be a client to a server. The requirement is that before sending the protobuf data I have to prepend the size of the protobuf data with 4 bytes. I am using Netty as my socket library. I have used the in-built protocolbuffer encoder and decoder of netty but I am still not getting the right result. This is the code I am running:
Pipeline code

```
public class SmpPipelineFactory implements ChannelPipelineFactory {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    /**
     * 
     */
    public SmpPipelineFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline p = pipeline();

        // Add Decoders
        p.addLast("frameDecoder", new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());      
        //p.addLast("frameDecoder",  new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1048576, 0, 4, 0, 4));        
        p.addLast("protobufDecoder", new ProtobufDecoder(Pdu.getDefaultInstance()));

        // Add encoders
        p.addLast("frameEncoder", new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
        //p.addLast("frameEncoder", new LengthFieldPrepender(4));
        p.addLast("protobufEncoder", new ProtobufEncoder());

        p.addLast("handler", new SmpChannelConnector());

        return p;
    }

}
```

Any help will help
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to explain a bit more about what is not working for you. If i look at the code in the protobuf RPC java library (https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-rpc-pro/ ) the class is DuplexTcpClientPipelineFactory or  DuplexTcpServerPipelineFactory, which is basically the same code as your's and it "works". Maybe the protobuf-rpc-pro library can already do what you need.

```
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline p = pipeline();

    RpcSSLContext ssl = bootstrap.getSslContext();
    if ( ssl != null ) {
            p.addLast(Handler.SSL, new SslHandler(ssl.createClientEngine()) );
    }

    p.addLast(Handler.FRAME_DECODER, new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder());
    p.addLast(Handler.PROTOBUF_DECODER, new ProtobufDecoder(DuplexProtocol.WirePayload.getDefaultInstance(),bootstrap.getExtensionRegistry()));

    p.addLast(Handler.FRAME_ENCODER, new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender());
    p.addLast(Handler.PROTOBUF_ENCODER, new ProtobufEncoder());

    // the connectResponseHandler is swapped after the client connection
    // handshake with the RpcClient for the Channel
    p.addLast(Handler.CLIENT_CONNECT, new ClientConnectResponseHandler());

    return p;
}
```

is your server a netty server , or just a netty client?

Comment: I am connecting to a C# server. I need a 4 byte length protobuf decoder.

Comment: i'm not the C# expert - but i guess you need to find out what is the binary format of the C# int "length" - 4bytes, signed or unsigned, litte-endian or big-endian. Then adapt the client java code to frame using this format. It might just work if you use the io.netty.handler.codec.LengthFieldPrepender as FRAME_ENCODER and LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder for the FRAME_DECODER ( which maybe only the server needs ).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. What I did is to write my own encoder and decoder based upon the protobuf data to be exchange. The main issue here was the endianess of the bytes over the channel.